# Wait on all child threads - Silverlight Unit Testing

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to do a unit test of a silverlight app and the method I call ends up calling another method which does something async. At this point the thread comes all the way out without completely finishing the process O am testing. The test then moves on an fails, is there a way I can take a thread, listen for any threads it creates and then waits for them to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this website [unit-testing-asynchronous-silverlight-code](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2008/06/04/unit-testing-asynchronous-silverlight-code/)

Comment: We're using Specflow which seems to be incompatible with this but it looks like they are working on a solution.